# Updating appengine-web.xml in IntelliJ based on run configuration

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ, I'd like to update the appengine-web.xml application value based on the run configuration.

For example, if I use my Development configuration I'd like the appengine-web.xml :

```
<application>mygoogleserverdeve</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

and if I use my Test configuration I'd like:

```
<application> mygoogleservertest</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

I just can't figure out how to dynamically set the application property in the appengine-web.xml based on the run config.
Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in the deployment configuration to run an Ant target prior to anything else, so I ended up just using an Ant replace task.  Similar to :

```
<target name="replaceTest" description="Set Test Server">
    <!-- Ensure GAE Test server is set -->
    <replace file="${basedir}/web/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml" token="SERVER_NAME" value="testserver" />
    <replace file="${basedir}/web/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml" token="deveserver" value="testserver" />
    <replace file="${basedir}/web/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml" token="prodserver" value="testserver" />
</target>
```